# select data from one table based on the data status on other table

Tags: mysql

My first data table is couponsnmaster

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
|couponsnid | couponid |  couponsn  |
+-----------+----------+------------+
|    1      |     1    |    1000    |
|    2      |     1    |    1001    |
|    3      |     1    |    1002    |
|    4      |     1    |    1003    |
|    5      |     1    |    1004    |
|    6      |     1    |    1005    |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

My second data table is distribute

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|   distid  |  couponid    |  couponsnid  |    status    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|    1      |      1       |       1      | distribute   |
|    2      |      1       |       2      | distribute   |
|    3      |      1       |       3      | distribute   |
|    4      |      1       |       1      |  returned    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to fetch all "couponsn" from "couponsnmaster" with respect to "couponid" except status is " distribute" or "sold" or "bonus" in table "distribute"....

Comment: is the foreign key `couponsnmaster.(couponsnid, couponid) <=> distribute.(couponsnid, couponid)` ? post the ddl

Comment: For clarity, why not provide the desired result

Comment: @ Strawberry  .. i want to show result are 1000,1003,1004,1005 from "couponsnmaster" table with respect couponid="1"

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT c.couponsn FROM
couponsmaster c INNER JOIN distribute d
ON c.couponsid = d.couponsid
WHERE d.status NOT IN('distribute','sold','bonus')
```

Comment: @Biegeleise ......... no data is fetched.... "couponsnid" is foreign in "distribute" table

Comment: You still haven't showed us the desired output.  I can imagine several queries you might want to run.

Comment: With respect to above two table i want to show result  are 1000,1003,1004,1005 from "couponsnmaster" table .

Comment: But `couponsn` `1000` has status `distribute`.  How do you explain this?

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen ....that  is only in first row....but later(Forth row) its status changed to "returned"...So i want fetch that also....